# How to create 12x8 swing button array

Tags: swing

I wonder if there is a way to change to source code format automatically produced 
by Net Beans IDE in GUI - applet applications. For example placement of the items in the source code are relational but what if I want them in absolute coordinates. I am asking this question because I need source code in that format so that I can easily change source code and can do some manual job. More specially, I want to create a Button Group of 12x8 array with no gap between them . But using IDE to do this takes long time and indeed, I couldn't even placed the buttons with no gap between them. Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to put together manually.  GUI builders usually harm more than they help.

Here's the test run:

[image: JButton Array Test]

And here's the code.  I put the classes together in one file to make it easier to paste.  The classes should be in separate files.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonArray implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButton Array Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        frame.add(buttonPanel.getMainPanel());

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
//      frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonArray());
    }

    public class ButtonPanel { 

        private static final int WIDTH = 12;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 8;

        private JButton[][] buttonArray;

        private JPanel mainPanel;

        public ButtonPanel() {
            buttonArray = new JButton[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
            createPartControl();
        }

        private void createPartControl() {
            mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(HEIGHT, WIDTH));

            for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                    buttonArray[j][i] = 
                            new JButton(createButtonText(j, i));
                    mainPanel.add(buttonArray[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }

        private String createButtonText(int j, int i) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.append("(");
            builder.append(i);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(j);
            builder.append(")");

            return builder.toString();
        }

        public JPanel getMainPanel() {
            return mainPanel;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some grid like layout for the panel (ex. FormLayout) configure it and simply add all buttons there.